# How can I show the Unity launcher with the mouse?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

I love that Unity launch panel hides itself when a window is over it, but when I move the mouse over to the left edge of the screen, the panel won't show itself so that I can launch other programs that are placed in it similar to the way Docky does.

Answer (score 5):

A change has been made this month to reveal the launcher on left edge now (after a one second timeout).

You can revert to the previous behavior of launcher reveal only in the top left corner launching the `unity-preferences` application.

Comment: Is there any way to change the timeout? It takes forever to open the launcher by pressing against the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if you just change the sensitivity, the dock could show up more easily. The higher the sensitivity the politer the touch to left side of the screen is required.